# Integral of product of independent functions is product of integrals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In the 4th book of Stein and Shakarchi, it is mentioned that: If $f_1,..,f_n$ are bounded and mutually independent functions on a probability space $(X,m)$, then
$$\int f_1(x)...f_n(x)dm = \left( {\int f_1(x)dm} \right)...\left(\int f_n(x)dm\right)$$ It is mentioned that this can be done by first verifying the above result for the case when the $f_i$ are linear combinations of characteristic functions and then taking the limit. I was able to handle the case of characteristic functions but I am unable to understand how to approximate the $f_i$ by simple functions which are themselves mutually independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience I will work under the condition that the functions $f_i$ are nonnegative.

For $n=1,2,\dots$ prescribe function $g_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto\frac1{n}{\lfloor nx\rfloor}$.

Then  $0\leq g_n\circ f_i\leq f_i$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n\circ f_i\to f_i$.

The boundedness of the $f_i$ guarantees that the image of $g_n\circ f_i$ is finite so that it can be recognized as a linear combination of characteristic functions.

The independence of the $f_i$ implies the independence of the $g_n\circ f_i$.

Comment: Do the $f_i$ have to be bounded? Even if they are unbounded, can we not write $\phi_n = \sum_{l=0}^{l=n^2-1} \left(\frac{l}{n}\chi_{f_i^{-1}[\frac{l}{n},\frac{l+1}{n})}\right)$

Comment: Well, that's another question. If they are not bounded then the construction I gave will not work, because $g_n\circ f_i$ can have an infinite image. Also in that case there are ways to approach them by linear combination of characteristic functions and if the functions $f_i$ are nonnegative then the equality you mention in your question stays valid. Things get tricky if the functions can take positive and negative values, because then the integral might fail to exist.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.